# How can I check if an application is registered to handle a particular URL scheme on macOS?

Tags: cocoa

On iOS I can check to see whether a particular URL scheme has an associated app by calling UIApplication's [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl?language=objc) method.  Is there an equivalent method in macOS?

If not, how does Firefox know how to populate a list of applications when I click on a link with a custom url scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services) for this.

[`LSCanURLAcceptURL()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1441854-lscanurlaccepturl) can test if a given application (specified by URL) can accept a given URL.

[`LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1445148-lscopyapplicationurlsforurl) will return the URLs of the app bundles for all applications which claim to handle that kind of URL. For `file:` URLs, it uses the filename extension or old-style type code. For other types of URLs, it uses the URL scheme. This is likely what Firefox uses to populate that list you mentioned.

If you just want the default app for a URL, use [`LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1448824-lscopydefaultapplicationurlforur). I don't recall if it does, but Firefox could, in theory, use this to pre-select the default in that list.

Some of the functionality of [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) is built on top of Launch Services. Its [`-URLForApplicationToOpenURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533391-urlforapplicationtoopenurl) method is basically a wrapper around `LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL()`. Unfortunately, it doesn't have methods that corresponds to the other Launch Services functions I mentioned.